# When did we have first calculations of moon phases?

Tags: astronomy

I'm interested in knowing more about the history around lunar tables and calculation of moon phases.

When did we have first (reliable) calculations of moon phases and first (reliable) lunar tables? When did they become widespread?

Reading through [History of astronomy (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_astronomy), it appears that we've had some calculations 200-100 BC at least (Greece), but maybe even earlier (the Maya).

**Edit**
To explain a bit better: I'm trying to find an answer to the question: At which point in history, were we able to tell the exact day on which moon phases will occur, for the next 2 months (for example)? Reliable meaning that most of the time (let's say 90%) the predictions were correct.

Comment: Can't you just count days forward? What is reliable to you? How far into the future does the prediction need to be?

Comment: @planetmaker thanks for the follow-up questions. I've updated the question.

Comment: The Babylonian [Astronomical diaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_astronomical_diaries) span over 7 centuries of nightly observations of the skies (weather permitting), and Babylonian data was one of the sources used in Ptolemy's Almagest. That Wikipedia article is brief, but there are more details in the external link to livius.org. The Babylonians knew lunar cycles well enough to predict eclipses.

Comment: @PM2Ring That's some very useful info, so many thanks for that! I'll go deeper into the Babylonian data and the livius.org.

Comment: @PM2Ring it could even make for an answer :)

Comment: I'd bet some time between 20,000 and 200,000 years ago

Comment: @planetmaker Perhaps. ;) But as James K mentions, knowledge of the period of the lunar cycle is probably *far* older. The [Ishango bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishango_bone) or the [Lebombo bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebombo_bone) *might* be lunar calendars. The former is around 20,000 years old, the latter is over 43,000 years old. OTOH, modern astronomy has more or less directly inherited the Babylonian / Chaldean data and we still use their base 60 system of subdividing angles and time, as I mentioned [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44126/16685).

Comment: @PM2Ring If you can put this info into an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.: )

Comment: The NASA site article [Oldest Lunar Calendars](https://sservi.nasa.gov/articles/oldest-lunar-calendars/) states that the Aurignacian Lunar Calendar, c. 32,000BCE shows phases of the moon and is the earliest from the archaeological record.

Comment: I do not know who "we" are, I never had this.

Comment: I think it could be during 2nd century, Using The Antikythera mechanism, an analog computer from ancient greece reliably predicts lunar phases that occur in a synodic month, which probably was invented in 2nd century B during the Hellenistic era. Not only does the antikythera mechanism predict various phases of the moon, it also can predict, eclipses/occulation, planetary motion, etc..

Comment: "for the next 2 months" is funny given that the concept (and word!) **month** originally meant one lunar phase. It might be more fruitful to ask when and why calendars started to redefine months as meaning something else.

Comment: The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month gives some background. It references e.g. the paper Goldstein, B. R. (2003).  [Ancient and Medieval Values for the Mean Synodic Month](https://www.pitt.edu/~brg/pdfs/brg_i_2.pdf). Journal for the History of Astronomy, 34(1), 65–74. https://doi.org/10.1177/002182860303400104 which gives various values proposed by Babylonians, Hindus, Ancient Greeks etc.